# Won't update because some index files failed to download/ hash sum mismatch

Tags: release-loki

I'm a new user and don't know much about EOS, but it said that the first thing new users need to do is update and upgrade

The problem is, I don't know how to fix this problem (screenshoot), I already try to find the way to fix from google but no one could fix this,

[image: how to fix it?]
It happens when I write sudo apt-update,
Does anybody know how to fix it ?
Thankyou

It's elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki 
(sorry for my bad english)